# Proof that inscribed circle's radius is always $\sqrt{{ab}}$

Tags: geometry, circles

In image $AD$ is diameter of circle , $MB$ and $NC$ are perpendicular to $AD$ , $AB=a$ and $CD=b$.
And small circle touches  these perpendiculars, diameter and big circle

[image]

I have found that radius of small circle is always equal to $\sqrt{{ab}}$ , but I can't find an exact way to prove it.How would you prove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denote the tangency points by $X,Y,Z$ according to the following picture.

[image]

First prove that $Y$ lies on $AX$ and that $Z$ lies on $DX$.

Then observe that $\triangle ABY \sim \triangle ZCD$. Conclude that $\dfrac{AB}{BY} = \dfrac{CZ}{CD}$. This means that $ab=AB \cdot CD = BY \cdot CZ$. However, it is clear that $BY=CZ=r$ where $r$ is the radius of the small circle, so $r=\sqrt{ab}$.

Comment: Can you show your way to prove that Y
 lies on AX
 and that Z
 lies on DX
.@timon92 I'm gonna compare to mine

Comment: @Anar It's a standard fact that follows by homothety. Since the circles are internally tangent, there is a positive homothety centered at the tangency point $X$ which maps the small circle to the big circle. This homothety maps the diameter $YZ$ to a diameter of the big circle which is parallel to $YZ$. There is only one such diameter: $AD$. Hence $YZ$ has to be mapped to $AD$. So, $Y$ has to be mapped to $A$ and $Z$ to $D$.